# jQuery Ajax authorization request header

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with AJAX request to my external API.

I tried to develop login from jQuery to API like that:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  crossDomain: true,
  cache: false,
  url: __Configuration.apiURL+"/login",
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {                  
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", Login.MakeAuth(email, password));  
  },
  success: function(data){
  }   
});
```

Everything looks ok when login and username are correct,

but when i tried to put wrong login and password then Ajax returns authorization window (prompt) from api..  so my problem is: how to prevent from that? I don't want to see this prompt...

Comment: ... and what do you want to see?

Comment: Something else, i want to inform user that data are incorrect, for example by alert

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to set statusCode on ajax request but anyway prompt from api always is shown

Comment: I've resolved my problem. I've added other WWW-Authentication response header to my nginx